# MPEG-DASH using apache2 server - result 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: android, linux, apache, mpeg-dash

I am trying to do MPEG-DASH streaming from apache2 server to my Android device.
On server side I have Ubuntu 15.10 machine, on client side I am using Android device with ExoPlayer library.
I have downloaded media files from http://www.bok.net/dash/tears_of_steel/.
I have configured Android app to use file from local server and MPD file is transferred correctly.
I have problem with transferring first media segment - init.mp4 file.
When my device request this file (URL is correctly achieved from MPD file), server response with code 415 (Unsupported Media Type).
The same result is when I try to download this file using wget.

I think, that problem may be with wrong recognized MIME type of media segments in stream (especially the first one, which causes the problem).
I have searched Internet to find a way how to configure apache server for DASH, but found no results.

How to configure apache server to work with DASH streaming?

Comment: For apache2 config for DASH, please see my answer here, although I don't know if it will solve your specific problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171529/how-to-setup-mpeg-dash-server-using-apache/36166779#36166779